# QueuePool limit reached for Flask application

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running an application with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

```
from config import FlaskDatabaseConfig
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object(FlaskDatabaseConfig())
db = SQLAlchemy(application)

@application.route("/queue/request", methods=["POST"])
    def handle_queued_request():
        stuff()
        return ""

def stuff():
    # Includes database queries and updates and a call to db.session.commit()
    # db.session.begin() and db.session.close() are not called
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=False, port=5001)
```

Now, from my understanding, by using Flask-SQLAlchemy I do not need to manage sessions on my own. So why am I getting the following error if I run several requests turn by turn to my endpoint?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/3o7r)
```

I've tried using `db.session.close()` but then, instead of this error, my database updates are not committed properly. What am I doing incorrectly? Do I need to manually close connections with the database once a request has been handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. The issue was that I had a lot of processes that were "idle in transaction" because I did not call `db.session.commit()` after making certain database SELECT statements using `Query.first()`

To investigate this, I queried my (development) PostgreSQL database directly using:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

Comment: Why is there a need to commit after a select query? I have the same problem but don't understand why this is the case. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Hi, I think that this fix did not solve the root of the problem. There may be in an issue in how you create your db connections in Flask. Personally, I think I had circular imports which created two connections for each request and one of them was not closed. Another potential issue was that I directly used model entities to make queries (like `User.query.get` instead of `db.session.query(User).get`. So I'd suggest checking how you create your db (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637324/shared-object-across-threads-in-flask for instance) and usage of queries from your model objects

Answer (score 3):

Just remove connection every time you make a query session to db.

```
products = db.session.query(Product).limit(20).all()
db.session.remove()
```

Comment: Hi Minh, thanks for your answer. Isn't this already handled by flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: @Konrad As of 04/12/2021, the answer is NO. Which is what I found out just now.

Comment: Hi Minh, I have better experience with Flask now and this is not an error I face nowadays. As far as I can remember the issue was related to idle database sessions. We currently have an application in production and we have never needed to call db.session.remove() manually.